# In React, Firebase auth user is null every time I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I got stuck with the below issue. I went through couple of SO questions and answers related to the same issue but none them working for me.

I am using firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged to check if user is already logged in but I am always getting user null whenever I refresh the page.

PFB code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home/components/Home';
import Footer from './Footer/components/Footer';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, withRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase/auth';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/components/Dashboard';
import * as actions from '../actions/index';
import {Map, List, fromJS} from 'immutable';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true, 
      authenticated: false, 
      user: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      //user is null every time I refresh the page
        if (user) {
        this.props.userLoading(false);
        this.props.authUser(true);
        this.props.storeUser(user.providerData);
        this.props.history.push('/dasboard');
      } else {
        this.props.userLoading(false);
        this.props.authUser(false);
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnMount(){
    this.unSubscribe();
  }

  render(){
    const { authenticated, loading } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          </div>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const user = state.getIn(['user', 'data'], List());
  const authenticate = state.getIn(['user', 'auth'], false);
  const userLoading = state.getIn(['user', 'loading'], false);

  return {
    user,
    authenticate,
    userLoading
  };
}

const actionsToProps = {
  storeUser: actions.storeUser,
  authUser: actions.authUser,
  userLoading: actions.userLoading
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, actionsToProps)(App))
```

auth.js:

```
import firebase from './firebase';

export const auth = firebase.auth();

export const logout = firebase.auth().signOut();

export const githubProvider = firebase.firebase_.auth.GithubAuthProvider();

export const twitterProvider = new firebase.firebase_.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();

export const facebookProvider = new firebase.firebase_.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
```

I am using firebase version 5.8.3.

I have tried with many possibilities like using async await, setTimeout but none of them are working.

Comment: What is your version of firebase? After v4.0.0 there were some changes to the event. You can read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged)

Comment: @bennygenel Thanks for your comment. I am using version 5.8.3

Comment: Try to Add your domain under Authorized Domains

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi Did you mean firebase?

Comment: Yes, in firebase.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi I already have localhost with default type under authorized domains and also xyz-4031.firebaseapp.com is added by default

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be signing out in auth.js:

`firebase.auth().signOut();`

Firebase queues the sign out operation and runs it when the Auth instance is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check and update in sometime